# I am having trouble inserting into table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having problem inserting data into my sqlite table in, i want to add ,update and delete users . While adding user I am getting error as:

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=new address=9849 age=text phone_number=123
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Customer_Info has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customer_Info(name,address,age,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private PersonAdapter adapter;
private String filter = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    populaterecyclerView(filter);
}
private void populaterecyclerView(String filter){
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    adapter = new PersonAdapter(dbHelper.personList(filter), this, mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);


    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.addMenu:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            goToAddUserActivity();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void goToAddUserActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecordActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}
My DatabaseHelper.class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Customers";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Customer_Info";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_AGE = "age";
public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_PH = "phone_number";
public static final String COLUMN_PERSON_Address = "address";

public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PERSON_Address + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_PERSON_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_PERSON_AGE + " NUMBER NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_PERSON_PH + " NUMBER NOT NULL );"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // you can implement here migration process
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void saveNewPerson(Person person) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_Address, person.getAddress());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME, person.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE, person.getAge());
    values.put(COLUMN_PERSON_PH, person.getPhone_number());

    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}

public List<Person> personList(String list) {
    String query;
    if (list.equals("")) {
        //regular query
        query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    } else {
        //filter results by filter option provided
        query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + list;
    }
    List<Person> peopleLinkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    Person person;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            person = new Person();
            person.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
            person.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME)));
            person.setAge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE)));
            person.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_Address)));
            person.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_PH)));
            peopleLinkedList.add(person);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return peopleLinkedList;
}

/**
 * Query only 1 record
 **/

public Person getPerson(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _id=" + id;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    Person receivedPerson = new Person();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        receivedPerson.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_Address)));
        receivedPerson.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_NAME)));
        receivedPerson.setAge(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_AGE)));
        receivedPerson.setPhone_number(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PERSON_PH)));

    }

    return receivedPerson;
}




}
```

}

Add users Activity:

```
public class AddRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText mNameEditText;
private EditText mAgeEditText;
private EditText mAddressEt;
private EditText mPh;
private Button mAddBtn;

private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_record);

    //init
    mNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    mAgeEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userAge);
    mAddressEt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addressAdd);
    mPh = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ph_no);
    mAddBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addNewUserButton);

    //listen to add button click
    mAddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //call the save person method
            savePerson();
        }
    });

}

private void savePerson(){
    String address = mAddressEt.getText().toString().trim();
    String name = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String age = mAgeEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String ph = mPh.getText().toString().trim();
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    if(name.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(age.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter an age", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(address.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter an occupation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(ph.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "You must enter an image link", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //create new person
    Person person = new Person(address, name, age,ph);
    dbHelper.saveNewPerson(person);

    //finally redirect back home
    // NOTE you can implement an sqlite callback then redirect on success delete
    goBackHome();

}

private void goBackHome(){
    startActivity(new Intent(AddRecordActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

}
I am making a normal form where i can perform CRUD operations in my application, by when submitting my form to add user I am getting the above mentioned error,Can any one suggest my what am I doing wrong , why the users are not being added.

Comment: Have you filled all fields (means edittext) before inserting data into database ?

Comment: **Way** too much code, and little effort spent directing us to where the problem is.  Please narrow down your question to 20-30 lines of code, where the problem is.

Comment: you should add return; after checking each edittext.isEmpty and displaying toast. so it will not insert data if any field is empty

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Sorry sir , My question is my data is not being inserted when i add in database i had one issue where i was sending text in age where as age only accepted Numbers , but i fixed it still i am getting this error

2018-10-03 13:03:32.233 11699-11699/com.planetearthsolution.kyc_pes E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=JOn address=world age=12 phone_number=159
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Customer_Info has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customer_Info(name,address,age,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: Are you planning to edit your question?

Comment: Why are you dropping your table on onUpgrade()?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know the whole situation but I had similar problems when adding a new row in a table after the table has been already created. If you are trying to add new row to the table after it has been created, try to remove the table and create it again.

to remove

```
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have entered wrong age**

```
Error inserting name=new address=9849 age=text phone_number=123
```

Age is number and you are inserting "text"

you can change it in your XML by forcing user to input text or number

**for you name and address edittext use**

```
        android:inputType="text"
```

**for your age and phone use**

```
        android:inputType="number"
```

Comment: I fixed it still getting same problem still giving me this error


2018-10-03 13:03:32.233 11699-11699/com.planetearthsolution.kyc_pes E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=JOn address=world age=12 phone_number=159
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Customer_Info has no column named name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Customer_Info(name,address,age,phone_number) VALUES (?,?,?,?)